# Can anyone tell why this JSON is not being read properly?

Tags: android, json

When I run my Android app, nothing comes up on the main screen. This was suspicious so I tried putting a few print statements to see if string values were actually being set. Nothing got printed to my console, so I looked in the logcat and found the following:

```
03-05 00:37:14.958: E/(9918): <s3dReadConfigFile:75>: Can't open file for reading
```

Can anyone see what's wrong with this code? It seems pretty straightforward to me and I don't see why it wouldn't work correctly.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ArrayList<contact> contacts = new ArrayList<contact>();

    File file = new File("contacts.json");
    String s = "Hello";
    //System.out.println(s);
    try {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while(in.hasNext()){
            sb.append(in.next());
        }
        System.out.println(s.substring(0,10));
        in.close();
        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(s);
          for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = ja.getJSONObject(i);
            contact c = new contact(); // Creates an empty contact object

            // Retrieves contact information from JSONObject
            String name = obj.getString("name");
            int employeeId = obj.getInt("employeeId");
            String company = obj.getString("company");
            String detailsURL = obj.getString("detailsURL");
            String imageURL = obj.getString("imageURL");
            long birthdate = obj.getLong("birthdate");

            //Sets contact values to retrieved JSON data and adds to the ArrayList
            c.setName(name);
            c.setEmployeeId(employeeId);
            c.setCompany(company);
            c.setDetailsURL(detailsURL);
            c.setImageURL(imageURL);
            c.setBirthdate(birthdate);

            contacts.add(c);
          }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
```

Comment: Have you given permission to access file ??

Comment: Where did you put your file?

Comment: The file is currently in the same directory as MainActivity.java, so how would I solve this issue? I'm sorry I'm very new to pathing

Answer (score 0):

Pass full path with file name in File Constructor instead of only file name. if file is inside SDCARD then do it as:

```
String Root_Dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
File file = new File(Root_Dir+"/contacts.json");
```

Comment: @Xonal : where you have placed `contacts.json` file ?

Comment: Same exact directory as MainActivity.java (I figured it would be easiest to find that way?)

Comment: @Xonal :  MainActivity.java  file is inside java packages so it's not possible to place any raw file inside package. so either put file inside assets folder or in sdcard

Comment: It's in the assets folder now, but to no avail. I'm considering just using a URL to get the JSON off the web because this problem is far too annoying.